# Reverse Engineer Database with Bookshelf.JS?

Tags: bookshelf.js

What is the process for generating bookshelf Model objects from an existing MySQL database?

The [examples on the Bookshelf.js site](http://bookshelfjs.org/) show several model objects...

```
var knex = require('knex')({client: 'mysql', connection: 
process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE_CONNECTION });
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    posts: function() {
        return this.hasMany(Posts);
    }
});
```

The closest the [Knex.js site](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-migrations) comes to this is mentioning migrations.  However, using their syntax...

```
$ npm install -g knex
$ npm install knex --save
$ npm install mysql --save
$ knex init
$ knex migrate:make knextest
```

... only generates one file with empty functions ...

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {

};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {

};
```

... which makes sense, since knex is NOT the ORM.  I guess I ended up here because Bookshelf didn't mention any tools for this.

On a side note, I've checked my `knexfile.js` and made sure it has a valid configuration:

```
development: {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'oogaboogs',
    database : 'knexdb'
  }
},
```

Is this not possible?  It would really suck to create thousands of Model objects by hand for an existing database.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Maybe just write an automigrate function like similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31119634/6702495

Answer (score 0):

You could use Yeoman-based [generator-bookshelf](https://github.com/melvey/generator-bookshelf).

Creating models is as simple as:

```
$ yo bookshelf:model
? Table Name users
? idAttribute id
? Add a relationship? No
```